# Typo3 Form Finisher, class not found

Tags: forms, typo3

I use TYPO3 8.7.8

I followed this guide to add a finisher to a form.
https://www.marco.zone/typo3-formular-finisher-zum-editor-hinzufuegen

In back-end i can choose my finisher but in front-end i got this error:

> Could not analyse class:
>   "MyVendor\MyExtensionName\Domain\Finishers\FluidFinisher" maybe not
>   loaded or no autoloader? Class
>   MyVendor\MyExtensionName\Domain\Finishers\FluidFinisher does not exist

and this is the base setup:

```
# BaseSetup.yaml
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          finishersDefinition:
            CleverreachSubscribe:
              implementationClassName: 'MyVendor\MyExtensionName\Domain\Finishers\FluidFinisher'
```

And this is the namespace of my class finisher that is inside my extension:
->\typo3conf\ext\myextensionname\Classes\Domain\Finishers\FluidFinisher.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyExtensioneName\Domain\Finishers;
```

I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good as far as I can see. Try:

- You use `composer`? Run `composer dump` to regenerate the autoloader.
- Check for typos
- Caches?

Comment: It was a composer problem.

Comment: Or use "Rebuild PHP Autoload Information" in install-tool of TYPO3.